# Terraform RDS instance errors with lowercase alphanumeric characters and hypens allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, rds

We have a rds cluster, and I'm trying to import instance to terraform.
However I'm getting the below error for aws_db_option_group and aws_db_parameter_group. It has the name as default:postgres-9-5 and default.postgres9.5 respectively.

> Error: module.rds.aws_db_option_group.amp_option: only lowercase
>   alphanumeric characters and hyphens allowed in "name"
>
> Error: module.rds.aws_db_parameter_group.amp_parameter: only lowercase
>   alphanumeric characters and hyphens allowed in parameter group "name"

terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.14
 + provider.aws v2.22.0

I found a issue reported long back: Looks like it was fixed for v1.10 version , any workaround for this issue pls. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11040

Comment: Try asking in devops space? I am looking for the answer as well

Comment: @Sand1512
I think , that bug fix is merged

Comment: This is the relevant GitHub issue - https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12144